# How do I iterate through a dictionary in Django Templates?

Tags: javascript, python, django, python-3.x, django-templates

I am trying to iterate through a dictionary in my django template and save the values to `window.obj`, but it is not working.

views.py:

```
def myView(req):
...
myDict = {'foo':"[1,2]", 'bar':"[3,4]"} 

return render(req, 'myPage.html', {'myDict':myDict})
```

myPage.html:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.obj = {}
window.obj["foo"] = "{{ myDict.foo }}";

{% for key, value in myDict %}

window.obj["{{ key }}"] = "{{ value }}";

{% endfor %}
</script>

...

<script> 
console.log(window.obj.foo); //prints {foo: "[1,2]"} 
console.log(window.obj.bar); //prints undefined
</script>
```

**Note:** I can't use `myDict.foo` on my actual project

What am I missing here?

Comment: Try using dict.items instead `{% for key, value in myDict.items %}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
{% for key, value in myDict.items %}
```